# Materialize Results to #Temp

Tags: sql, t-sql

--Edit to include entire query, with error correct.

I am trying to create a Temp Table in an existing query that can be joined to.
I am getting the following error.

```
(746739 row(s) affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Invalid object name 'POD_TB'.
```

This is my first attempt with temp tables, I know I am missing something simple.
Thank you in advance.

```
DROP TABLE #POD_TB
CREATE TABLE #POD_TB
(
Delivery varchar(60)
  ,Shipment_Number varchar(60)
  ,Shipping_Carrier varchar(60)
  ,Tracking_Number varchar(60)
  ,Ship_Method varchar(60)
  ,POD_Signature varchar(60)
  ,POD_Date varchar(60)
  ,POD_Time varchar(60)
)

INSERT INTO #POD_TB
SELECT SHIPMENTS.Delivery
  ,SHIPMENTS.Shipment_Number
  ,PROOF_OF_DELIVERY.Shipping_Carrier
  ,PROOF_OF_DELIVERY.Tracking_Number
  ,PROOF_OF_DELIVERY.Ship_Method
  ,PROOF_OF_DELIVERY.POD_Signature
  ,PROOF_OF_DELIVERY.POD_Date
  ,PROOF_OF_DELIVERY.POD_Time
FROM
SHIPMENTS 
LEFT JOIN PROOF_OF_DELIVERY
ON SHIPMENTS.Shipment_Number = PROOF_OF_DELIVERY.Delivery_Or_Shipment
WHERE Load_Date IN
(
SELECT MAX(Load_Date)
FROM PROOF_OF_DELIVERY
GROUP BY Delivery_Or_Shipment
)


SELECT DISTINCT GI.GOODS_ISSUE_DOCUMENT_ID
,GI.SALES_ORDER_ID
,GI.SALES_ORDER_LINE_ID
,GI.SALES_ORDER_TYPE_CODE
,GI.DELIVERY_HEADER_ID
,GI.DELIVERY_ITEM_ID
,FD.FISCAL_MONTH_CODE
,GI.MATERIAL_NUMBER
,GI.SHIPPED_QTY
,SO.ORDERER_NAME
,SO.CREATED_BY
,SO.CONTACT_PERSON
,GI.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_ID
,GI.SHIP_TO_CUSTOMER_ID
,GI.ORIGINAL_COMMIT_DATE
,GI.SHIP_FROM_PLANT_ID
,GI.ACTUAL_PGI_DATE
,GI.CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER
,GI.SHIPPED_PRICE
,(GI.SHIPPED_PRICE * GI.SHIPPED_QTY) AS EXT_SHIPPED_PRICE
,GI.SALES_ORGANIZATION_CODE
,GI.DELIVERY_NOTE_PRIORITY_CODE
,FD.FISCAL_WEEK_CODE
,DV.DIVISION_CODE
,DN.Delivery_Item_Creation_Date
,SOLD.CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME AS SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME
,SHIP.CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME AS SHIP_TO_CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME
,SHIP.Customer_Site_Name
,SHIP.REGION_NAME
,MATD.MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION
,MATD.STANDARD_COST
,(MATD.STANDARD_COST * GI.SHIPPED_QTY) AS EXT_STANDARD_COST
,MATD.GLOBAL_EVENT
,PLT.LEAD_TIME_FOR_ORIGINAL_COMMIT
,OPRM.BASE_PART_CODE
,MATD.PRODUCT_INSP_MEMO
,MATD.MATERIAL_PRICING_GROUP_CODE
,MATD.MATERIAL_STATUS AS MMPP
,PIM.PIM_PBG_GROUPING
,SOL.SHIPPING_CONDITION
,SVO.SERVICE_ORDER_NUM 
,SO.CREATION_TIME AS SO_CREATION_TIME
,SOL.CREATED_TIME AS SO_LINE_CREATED_TIME
,SOL.SHIPPING_POINT
,SDT.SALES_DOCUMENT_TYPE_CODE AS SVO_DOCUMENT_TYPE_CODE
,EQU.EQUIPMENT_NUM
,EQU.SERIAL_NUMBER
,EQU.CUSTOMERTOOLID
,POD.Shipment_Number
,POD.Shipping_Carrier
,POD.Tracking_Number
,POD.Ship_Method
,POD.POD_Signature
,POD.POD_Date
,POD.POD_Time
,DATEDIFF(dd,SO.CREATION_TIME,GI.ACTUAL_PGI_DATE) AS Cycle_Time_to_PGI_Days 
,DATEDIFF(hh,SO.CREATION_TIME,GI.ACTUAL_PGI_DATE) AS Cycle_Time_to_PGI_Hours    

FROM GOODS_ISSUE AS GI
INNER JOIN dbo.Delivery_Notes AS DN
ON GI.DELIVERY_HEADER_ID = DN.DELIVERY_HEADER_CODE AND GI.DELIVERY_ITEM_ID = DN.DELIVERY_ITEM_CODE
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer_View AS SOLD
ON GI.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_ID = SOLD.CUSTOMER_CODE
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer_View AS SHIP
ON GI.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_ID = SHIP.CUSTOMER_CODE
INNER JOIN dbo.MATERIAL_DETAILS AS MATD
ON GI.MATERIAL_NUMBER = MATD.MATERIAL_NUMBER
INNER JOIN dbo.OPR_MATERIAL_DIM AS OPRM
ON OPRM.MATERIAL_NUMBER = GI.MATERIAL_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN dbo.SM_DATE_DIM AS FD
ON CAST(FD.CALENDAR_DAY AS DATE) = CAST(GI.ACTUAL_PGI_DATE AS DATE)
LEFT JOIN dbo.DIM_PUBLISHED_LEAD_TIME_COMMIT AS PLT
ON PLT.MATERIAL_NUMBER = OPRM.BASE_PART_CODE
LEFT JOIN dbo.PRODUCT_INSP_MEMO_DIM AS PIM
ON PIM.PRODUCT_INSP_MEMO = MATD.PRODUCT_INSP_MEMO
INNER JOIN  dbo.SM_SALES_ORDER_LINE_FACT AS SOL
ON SOL.SALES_ORDER_CODE = GI.SALES_ORDER_ID AND SOL.SALES_ORDER_LINE_CODE = GI.SALES_ORDER_LINE_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.SM_SALES_ORDER_FACT AS SO
ON SO.SALES_ORDER_CODE = GI.SALES_ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.SM_DIVISION_DIM AS DV
ON SO.DIVISION_SID = DV.DIVISION_SID
LEFT JOIN dbo.SERVICE_ORDER_FACT AS SVO
ON SVO.SERVICE_ORDER_NUM = SO.SERVICE_ORDER_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN dbo.SM_SALES_DOCUMENT_TYPE_DIM AS SDT
ON SDT.SALES_DOCUMENT_TYPE_SID = SVO.SALES_DOCUMENT_TYPE_SID
LEFT JOIN dbo.SM_EQUIPMENT_DIM AS EQU
ON EQU.EQUIPMENT_SID = SVO.EQUIPMENT_SID
LEFT JOIN #POD_TB AS POD
ON POD.Delivery = GI.DELIVERY_HEADER_ID


WHERE GI.ACTUAL_PGI_DATE > GETDATE()-32
AND GI.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_ID IN (0010000252,0010000898,0010001121,0010001409,0010001842,0010001852,0010001879,0010001977,0010001978,0010002021,0010002202,0010002227,0010002982,0010003118,0010003176,0010003294,0010005492,0010006904,0010007048,0010007080,0010010381,0010010572,0010010905,0010011999,0010012014,0010012048,0010012571,0010013124,0010013711,0010013713,0010013824,0010014180,0010014188,0010014333,0010015059,0010015313,0010015414,0010015541,0010015544,0010015550)
```

Comment: Sounds like you're joining on `POD_TB` but should be joining on `#POD_TB`.  Hard to tell without seeing the rest of your query though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting that you cut the query off at the exact line that the error is on :)

I'm guessing you just forgot the hash (`#`) when querying *from* the temp table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GI.GOODS_ISSUE_DOCUMENT_ID
...
FROM #POD_TB    // <-- notice the #
...
```

Also, a temp table might not be necessary - if you can join to the "temp" query as a subquery you may get better performance (assuming you don;t need the results for subsequent queries).